# crop image function in camera preview screen in ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Solution for invoking a crop image function on previewing a camera image.I had tried this code below.

```
var options = {
      quality: 50,
      destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
      sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
      allowEdit: true,
      encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
        correctOrientation:true
    };
 try{
      $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {
        var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
        image.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;

      }, function(e) {
        alert(e);
      });
    } catch(e){
      alert(e);
    }
  };

 getpicture function is invoked by cordova camera plugin. while coded allowedit as true. it invokes the crop image function after clicking ok. but I want to invoke the crop function before placing ok button(In preview screen).
```

Answer (score 0):

My code is working properly.Try it (I am using both option - Take photo and browse photo)
 **Controller Code**

```
.controller("CameraController", function ($scope, $cordovaCamera) {
                $scope.takePhoto = function () {
                  var options = {
                    quality: 50,
                    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
                    sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
                    allowEdit: true,
                    encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
                    targetWidth: 100,
                    targetHeight: 100,
                    popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
                    saveToPhotoAlbum: true
                };

                    $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function (imageData) {
                        $scope.imgURI = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
                    }, function (err) {
                        // An error occured. Show a message to the user
                    });
                };

                $scope.choosePhoto = function () {
                  var options = {
                    quality: 75,
                    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
                    sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
                    allowEdit: true,
                    encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
                    targetWidth: 300,
                    targetHeight: 300,
                    popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
                    saveToPhotoAlbum: false
                };

                    $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function (imageData) {
                        $scope.imgURI = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
                    }, function (err) {
                        // An error occured. Show a message to the user
                    });
                };
})
```

**HTML Code**

```
<ion-view view-title="Camera">
    <ion-content>
        <div class="card">
          <button class="button button-full button-assertive" ng-click="takePhoto()">
        Take Photo
        </button>
        <button class="button button-full button-assertive" ng-click="choosePhoto()">
        Choose Photo
        </button>
        </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: It invokes the cropping after camera preview screen, I want to invoke the cropping in Preview screen itself.

Comment: It will capture image then cropping with preview will show then you will save image